# How to make child with position absolute scroll with parent?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I want to have buttons in scrollable div and absolute position child directly bellow buttons but NOT inside the scrollable div.

[image]

[image]

When I scroll the div that contains button, I want the content below button (blue square) also scroll with the div so the blue square is always directly below the button. As it is now, the blue square always stays in the same place. But, when I make the parent position relative, blue square is inside the scrollable div (the one with black border) and I want it outside.

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid black; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;">
       <button style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</button>
       <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;">
       <button style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</button>
       <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;">
       <button style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</button>
       <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 250px;">
       <button style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</button>
       <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have some idea how to make this work? I was looking through stackoverflow and it didn't help and I think I understand positioning quite well but maybe not well enough. If you have an idea how to fix  positioning or do it completely different way I would be grateful for any answer :)

Comment: Is the container `height: 50px;` intentionally to display the boxes outside of black border?

Answer (score 0):

You can `absolute` position the blue boxes `relative` to parent container, and add a `top: 100%;` to align them at the bottom of the container.

Also please use CSS instead of inline styles, it helps to easily  read understand what is going on.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.bluebox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <div class="bluebox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```